# Finding a common way to slide 'div's by clicking on the buttons for each of them

Tags: jquery

My HTML consists of lines of text(questions) and a button beside each to show/hide answers.
It is something like this.

```
<div id="test">
<ul>
<li>ques 1 <button>view/hide answer</button> </li>
  <div id="ans1">
   Answer 1
  </div>
<li>ques 2 <button>view/hide answer</button></li>
  <div id="ans2">
   Answer 2
  </div>
.
.
.
</ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a single function which can take the id of the clicked button or say the class of button and show/hide the div after it.
Using jQuery I can provide different ids to each and write code for the same but that'll be a foolish thing to do as I have a lot of questions to show. I hope I'm able to explain myself well.
There may be a very easy way to do it but unfortunately I just can't get to it.
Hope someone out there will help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of jQuery methods that will help you out:

- `next` - Probably your best bet.
- `nextAll`

To show the next element after a `button` element, do this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

If you change your layout and the the `div` happens not to be the very next element, then you'll need to use `nextAll` with an appropriate selector, which looks at all subsequent sibling elements, not just the very next one.

Comment: I seem to have made a mistake in posting my HTML code. The button is not after the 'li', rather inside it.

Comment: $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll("div").slideToggle();
    })
This is what I'm trying without success.

Comment: If the button is within the `li`, and the `div` is not, then you have invalid markup. Put the `div` in the `li` after the button. Sorry, I should have noticed the your markup was invalid from the beginning.

Comment: It's not your fault. I edited my post after mentioning it to you. I kept the 'div' out of 'li' for another purpose. Nonetheless, I now have a working piece of code. Thank you so much for your help and sorry to bother you for such petty issues.

Comment: It's no bother. Just know that having a `div` element as a child of a `ul` is not valid HTML according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/ul) and the W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#edef-UL)

Comment: You picked it up sooner than I could. What can be done in this case? I want an ordered list and I want the answers hidden just after it and I don't want the validator scoffing at me. Can you suggest something?

Comment: `div` elements are allowed within the `li` elements, so you could put them in there. Or perhaps put all the `div` elements after the `ul`. You may need to tweak the CSS a little, but either of those suggestions should provide you with a workable resolution.

Comment: I just checked it on validator. It doesn't seem to be concerned about 'div's wihtin 'ul', however, I got errors somewhere else. I am adding a few programming statements within the 'div', how shall I escape the '<' as used in a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$(function(){
    $("#test button").click(function(){
       //next() will get the next sibling of the button clicked.
       $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: @steady_daddy - Did you try this?

Comment: Thanks Shankar but that's not helping me.

Answer (score 2):

This does exactly what you want:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
});
```

It hides the first element right after the parent element of the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/hxRuG/2/

Comment: I'd recommend `.toggle()` instead of `.hide()`, but excellent otherwise

Comment: Thanks Nayish but that's not helping me.